# Bypass limit of 239 characters of sqlplus

Tags: oracle, batch-file, sqlplus

I loop on each line of a file, and each line has more than 3000 characters length. But when I execute my .bat, and after the SQLPlus connection, the console window contains the message: http://puu.sh/l6vOI/6bba21982b.png

> Traduction : the beginning of the string " " SO100ACa4 ... " is too long - the maximal size is 239 characters.

I tested using `Set VERIFY OFF` and `SET LINESIZE 4000`, but nothing worked.

Here is a part of my batch script:

```
for /f "delims=" %%f IN ('dir /b "%NomFichierU%*.txt"') DO (
    for /f tokens^=*^ delims^=^ eol^= %%l IN ('type "%%f"') DO (
        echo %%l
        sqlplus -L %user%/%pwd%@%db% @C:\Hardis\NDL\SQL\MHUHMS.sql "%%l"
    )
    move "%%f" "SLD_SLDHI\SAVE\%%f.%HHMMSS%"    
)
```

How to work around this character limit?

Comment: Getting the error message in English would make it easier for us to understand it, can you somehow do that?

Comment: @ammoQ I edit my question, sorry

Comment: Try setting `l` variable instead of passing it on command line: type `set "l=%%l"` on a new line after `echo %%l` and remove `"%%l"` from sqlplus parameters.

Comment: @wOxxOm Ow... I don't know why, but this take only the last line of my file... When i put an `echo %%l` it's the good line of my file, but when i put after `set "l=%%l"` and after `echo %%l` isn't the same line... it's the last of my file...

Comment: @wOxxOm my code : http://puu.sh/l6zE8/d565fb24a5.png

Comment: Use [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) and `!l!`

Comment: @wOxxOm Thank's it's ok ! I continu to make my test and post it on answer later. Thank's !

Comment: @wOxxOm Are you available to discuss in chat ? You help me on different subject last days and i've some questions on this subject... Thank's